# How to convert a string to decimal for Summing using Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, sum, type-conversion

Below is the statement in question. It keeps throwing an exception saying "input string was not in the correct format"

```
totalAmount = QDL.Document.Totals.Total.Sum(s => decimal.Parse(s.valueTotal));
```

My totalAmount variable is of a decimal type and "Total" is a list of containing valueTotal which is also of a string data type.

One constraint  is that my valueTotal HAS to be of string data type (that cannot change) and it has to write the sum of all those totals to totalAmount which has to be of decimal data type.

PLEASE HELP!

UPDATE:
Implemented the following as suggested by Styx in the comments:

```
totalAmount = QDL.Document.Totals.Total.Sum(s => { decimal result; Decimal.TryParse(s.valueTotal, NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result); return result; });
```

It now just keeps returning zero and not Parsing my string. see the screenshot below taken during debugging:

[Debugging Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9KkZ.png)

Comment: use `TryParse()` rather

Comment: please show a `valueTotal` example

Comment: @styx an example of value total is 100.00

Comment: @Rahul cannot use TryParse there because it returns a boolean value (true or false) and I cannot sum boolean values.

Comment: @NickWeidemann you can use try parse like this        `.Sum( s = > {
                    decimal result;
                      Decimal.TryParse(s.valueTotal, NumberStyles.None,  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result);
                    return result;
                    });`

Comment: @styx I have made some progress using your suggestion and have updated my post to reflect that. Doesn't seem to be Parsing my String. Keeps returning zero.

Comment: @NickWeidemann change `NumberStyles.None` to `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TryParse()` like

```
QDL.Document.Totals.Total.Sum(s => 
                 decimal.Tryparse(s.valueTotal, out decimal val)
                 ? val : 0);
```

Comment: The problem is that this statement: "decimal.Tryparse(s.valueTotal, out decimal val)" returns a boolean value. This possibility should never exist when trying to Sum.

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM SOLVED!

Big thanks to @Styx for the answer.

The below implementation worked perfectly as needed:

```
totalAmount = QDL.Document.Totals.Total.Sum(s => 
    { 
        decimal result;
        Decimal.TryParse(s.valueTotal, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result);
        return result; 
    });
```

Thanks again.